# How to augment the map returned by a ResponseWriter's Header()

Tags: dictionary, go, http-headers

So I'm sure I'm trying to cheat here, but the ResponseWriter docs has a method 'Header()' which returns the Header object it's using.
https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Header

Now I'm getting a http.Response from somewhere else, and I want to copy across all the headers from that into my ResponseWriter.

Now, I could use a for loop like this:

```
for k := range resp.Header 
    w.Header().Add(k, resp.Header.Get(k))
}
```

Logically, it also made sense for me to just change the reference from the ResponseWriter's header, to the Response's header, however it seems like the ResponseWriter type is actively trying to stop me from doing that.

Something stupid like this comes to mind

```
w.Header() = resp.Header
```

Or

```
rwHeader := w.Header()
rwHeader = resp.Header
```

Obviously both of these make no sense and do not work at all, but hopefully conveys the idea of what I'm trying to do.

Can anyone offer an explanation of why what I'm trying to do doesn't work? Or maybe it does and I'm just not seeing the way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write that loop yourself. Go 1.18 saw the addition of package [`golang.org/x/exp/maps`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps), which provides a convenient [`Copy` function](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/maps#Copy):

> ```golang
> func Copy[M ~map[K]V, K comparable, V any](dst, src M)
> ```
>
> `Copy` copies all key/value pairs in `src` adding them to `dst`. When
> a key in `src` is already present in `dst`, the value in `dst` will be
> overwritten by the value associated with the key in `src`.

```golang
import "golang.org/x/exp/maps"
// ...
maps.Copy(w.Header(), resp.Header)
```

---

However, note that, because a response can contain [duplicate headers](https://pkg.go.dev/net/url#Values), the use of `maps.Copy` isn't exactly equivalent to your loop:

```golang
for k := range resp.Header 
    w.Header().Add(k, resp.Header.Get(k))
}
```

Contrary to `maps.Copy`, your loop retrieves only the *first* header value corresponding to each header name present in `resp.Header`.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

`w` is an [http.ResponseWriter](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter) which is an interface type - so only has methods and no directly accessible fields. It has, as you know, a method to get the underlying `Header` map.

It does not, however, have a "Setter" method to replace the map. So the only way to copy over header values is by hand like your cited loop does.